# Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down? 500 Internal Server Error - HttpException

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I am working in my project in 2 different servers. The code is cloned from bitbucket so is exactly the same, but in one of them I get this error on every HTTP request:

```
Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?
500 Internal Server Error - HttpException
```

S.O. Ubuntu 16.04

When I run `service elasticsearch status` I get this:

```
    elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-01-15 11:05:25 CET; 1h 16min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1366 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0

Jan 15 11:05:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Jan 15 11:05:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

When I run `fos:elastica:populate` I got this error:

```
[Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException]
Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?
```

And running `curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200` I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I was searching for 5 days and think this issue is something about permissions.

Comment: where is your code

Comment: curl does not seem fine

Comment: looks like you need to open the port, like with iptables

Comment: I'm having the same Curl error, I don't think it's php related. I recently upgraded from Ubutnu 14.04 to 16.04 and now this problem.

Comment: I think this question is also asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661472/couldnt-connect-to-host-elasticsearch-down-500-internal-server-error-httpex

Comment: You elasticsearch service is stopped:  `Active: active (exited)`. Try to start it again and check latest log messages (`/var/log/elasticsearch` usually), if it will exit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @antonbormotov. I was searching about to start elasticsearch and found [this response.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/9)

> It seems that to get Elasticsearch to run on 16.04 you have to set
>   START_DAEMON to true on /etc/default/elasticsearch. It comes commented
>   out by default, and uncommenting it makes Elasticsearch start again
>   just fine.
>
> Be sure to use systemctl restart instead of just start because the
>   service is started right after installation, and apparently there's
>   some socket/pidfile/something that systemd keeps that must be released
>   before being able to start the service again

It's running now!